# What can convert .mfd files to a different format?

Tags: python, nfc, mifare

I have .mfd files and I want to import my information in .mfd file to python in order to save in database(sqlite3) .Someone can help me or give me the way to do...thank you!

I use libnfc (nfc-mfclassic) to read all block in tag and then I got .mfd. If I want to save data like that  to database in python .What should I have to do ...

my tag is mifare 1k

I run this thing :`nfc-mfclassic r a dumptest.mfd`   in terminal (Ubuntu) to get all of data

```
Usage: nfc-mfclassic r|w a|b <dump.mfd> [<keys.mfd>]
  r|w           - Perform read from (r) or write to (w) card
  a|b           - Use A or B keys for action
  <dump.mfd>    - MiFare Dump (MFD) used to write (card to MFD) or (MFD to card)
  <keys.mfd>    - MiFare Dump (MFD) that contain the keys (optional)
Or: nfc-mfclassic x <dump.mfd> <payload.bin>
  x             - Extract payload (data blocks) from MFD
  <dump.mfd>    - MiFare Dump (MFD) that contains wanted payload
  <payload.bin> - Binary file where payload will be extracted
```

Comment: What's an .mfd file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What program is used to create mfd files? Or you mean mdf?

Comment: I use libnfc to use nfc device(ARC122) for read data in tag (all of block ) so I use nfc-mfclassic run in terminal (I use Ubuntu) then it save all of data in .mfd file(mifare dump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a program to read dumps of nfc-mfclassic in Python: http://habrahabr.ru/post/141213/ (page is in Russian, you can use GoogleTranslate or scroll to "Программа на питоне, которая читает данные из дампа полученного с помощью nfc-mfclassic" section). After it use python-sqlite (http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) to save data to sqllite.

Comment: sorry I'm new in python ..I want to know about directory that I have to save file .py , I don't know what it mean >>#!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: See this page http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-July/030634.html about running python files in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try my Mifare dumps parser https://github.com/zhovner/mfdread
Code is pretty simple, so you can modify it to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The .mfd look like it is just a binary representation of the blocks on the card.

So if you do: od -tx2 -v mycard.mfd

The output is simply the hexadecimal values you would expect from looking at the dump as nfc-mfclassic shows you.